# MATLAB implementation Spline Fitting

Tags: approximation, interpolation, filters, spline

[image]

Check the attached problem please. I am a beginner in spline fitting and have a few questions:

1) How to find the coefficients c[n]. Is it by DTFT?
2) I understand how to find the derivative but not sure about how to deal with fractional translation?
3) What's the right function in matlab to obtain the (discrete) samples of a uniform spline function

Thanks!